# how to upload and store image in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to upload an image and want to store in a database. i have create field in table name picture type blob

```js
function bs_input_file() {
 $(".input-file").before(
  function() {
   if ( ! $(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost') ) {
    var element = $("<input type='file' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
    element.attr("name",$(this).attr("name"));
    element.change(function(){
     element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
    });
    $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function(){
     element.click();
    });
    $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function(){
     element.val(null);
     $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
    });
    $(this).find('input').css("cursor","pointer");
    $(this).find('input').mousedown(function() {
     $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
     return false;
    });
    return element;
   }
  }
 );
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Pic">Picture/File</label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">   
   
<div class="input-group input-file" > 
   <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-choose" type="button">Choose</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pic" name = "ID" placeholder='Choose a file...' />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-danger btn-reset " type="button">Reset</button>
      </span>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

this is i write to upload image now i want to store this image into database. and then want to retrieve and show an image also.

Comment: better you store images in one folder in your project folder and store path in database..so when you want to retrieve you can retrieve from your folder it self

Comment: @Dr.Strange thanks for giving minus. i have tried this image is not display as i asked this question before. kindly help other not giving minus point

Comment: you have to save the path location in database, not an image.  Better solution is you store the image in one folder and store the respective path in database. When you need to show the image in front-end just retrieve the path location from the database and  show the image.

Comment: @user3663 actually it is online randon user upload image

Comment: @Muthusamy kindly guide me what to do further according to my code i have given

Comment: yeah whats problem then. if it is online random user upload image.save the image path for the particular userid and show them when they logged in or when ever you want

Comment: @Sarah_Salar   just verify this link that much more better https://www.onlinebuff.com/article_step-by-step-to-upload-an-image-and-store-in-database-using-php_40.html

Comment: i have read mostly to store image as blob

Comment: @user:5139148 hiii have one doubt